# Does Google AutoML Vision support Tiff files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

[The text transcription feature does.](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) [But the AutoML documentation doesn't list TIFF as a supported file type](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare). Is that documentation outdated?

Comment: This link says it does https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned two different products, the first link you shared is from [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) which are pre-trained models and indeed supports TIFF files as is mentioned in the Support Images [page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files). And the second link you mentioned belongs to [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/) where you can train your own models and doesn't support TIFF files, the difference between products is mentioned in the "NOTE" section.

Comment: Thanks. What "NOTE" section are you referring to?

Comment: In the documentation page for [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/) the "Note" mentions that if you don't need a custom model solution, the Cloud Vision API provides general image labeling, face and text detection.